# Get number of current failed/skipped/ok tasks in ansible play

Tags: ansible

How can I determine how many "changed", "skipped", "ok" tasks have run so far?

Surely this information is available, because at the end of the run, ansible shows the "play recap".

I found nothing in ["special variables"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you're trying to do with that.

The number of *changed*, *skipped*, *failed*, *rescued* and so on tasks is stored in `stats`, which is set interally by using [the module `set_stats`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_stats_module.html). 
This is passed along in the standard callback plugin in `v2_playbook_on_stats`, which you can override/extend by creating your own `stdout_callback` plugin.
Thus, if you'd like, you could have a running tally of the stats.

However, if you wish to use it during a playbook, I'd first ask what you're trying to accomplish with that. I haven't seen any resources on reading data set with `set_stats` yet.

Comment: I don't feel like hacking the plugins. :( I was hoping I could use it during a play - specifically, to reboot the server after initial provisioning (if `0<changed`).

Comment: To do that, I would recommend using either `register` or `notify`. I'd say that `notify`, the [attribute for using handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change), is probably what will solve your use-case.

Comment: I was using notify but it was getting messy, and there are precedence conditions to take into account (depends on whether tasks, pre-tasks, roles, etc. run) and so it became too messy to maintain. I was hoping to depend on the final tally of tasks. Maybe I'll make a feature request at the repo. Thanks again.

Comment: Understandable. The best of luck! If it's too convoluted, you might have to resolve to one big `when`.